# Syntax Error{} AJAX success cannot read JSON returned from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I need some help here. I'm sending simple request to server, and the return I expected is JSON as data type. But when I checked in development tools console log I get "parsererror SyntaxError {}" and "parsererror".

How can I make this right? Below is the code.

JQuery

```
$(':submit').live('click', function() {

    $.ajax({

            type : 'post',        
            url: 'testJSON.php',
            beforeSend:console.log('sending...'),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){

                console.log(data.status);
                // do magic
                },

            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);

                },

            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {

                console.log(status);

                }

        });

    return false;
    });
```

and this is the testJSON.php

```
<?php

$data = array(

    "status" => 1,
    "firstname" => "foo",
    "lastname" => "bar",

);

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" ');
echo json_encode($data);


exit();

?>
```

FYI I use the latest version of WAMP. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please note that you have invalid JSON and you've posted everything except the JSON ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm not sure what you mean by invalid JSON... if you mean why I sending request to server without JSON, simply because the data that needed to run the php script stored in $_SESSION[]

Comment: You said that you were getting `parsererror` when parsing JSON... Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: It's true. I try to preview the testJSON.php, then Copy text from the browser and paste it inside online JSON validator (jsonlint.com) and I get a Valid JSON... still don't know why the JS can't read it as JSON.

Comment: Do you save `testJSON.php` as UTF-8 with BOM or without BOM?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario no I'm not Include Unicode Signature (BOM), or should I?

Comment: You shouldn't. I asked because it's a common cause of invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Set the header of the content to type of json... Here is an example of setting header type.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

In jQuery 1.4 onwards the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner.

Any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.8.3. I try this solution but the code still not working. I run the preview of the php script the data successfully converted into JSON type, I don't understand why AJAX can't receive it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

remove `"` from here

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" ');
```

should be

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: By setting `dataType: 'json'` the data is already (attemptedly) parsed

Comment: @GeenHenk Yeah I noticed that, thanks for correcting the mistake...:)

Comment: @GeenHenk I already removed it, but still get parsererror SyntaxError{} in my log ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I got an error at the **beforeSend** parameter. The statements shall be encapsulated in a function:

```
...    
beforeSend: function() {console.log('sending...')},
...
```

After that everything worked. Maybe it also depends on the jQuery version. Which one did you use? I tried with versions 1.8.1 and upwards

Comment: I'm using V 1.8.3. and the code work for me.. the reason iI use this parameter so that I know the AJAX works for the first place (and by the way the code is ... beforeSend:console.log('sending...')... without function(){})